# Make comma separated list from different paths

Tags: javascript

I have list of paths as follows in multiple lines.

```
abc/xyz/../a1.txt
abc/xyz/../a2.txt
abc/xyz/../a3.txt
abc1/xyz/../a4.txt
abc1/xyz/../a5.txt
abc1/xyz/../a6.txt
```

i want to remove all paths and extract only file names as follows

`"a1.txt","a2.txt","a3.txt"`     and

```
"a4.txt","a5.txt","a6.txt"
```

pls help me.

Comment: What does this have to do with angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to convert a multi-line string with paths into an object that will have an array of file names per folder, where the folder name is used as the object's property name:

```
// Test data, with some border cases:
var paths = " abc/xyz/../a1.txt\n" +
            "abc/xyz/../a2.txt\r\n" +
            "   \n" +
            " no-folder.txt \n" +
            "abc/xyz/../a3.txt     \n" +
            "   abc1/xyz/../a4.txt\n" +
            "abc1/xyz/../a5.txt\n" +
            "abc1/xyz/../a6.txt\n" +
            "   ";
var filesPerFolder = paths.split(/\r\n|\n/).reduce(function (filesPerFolder, path) {
    path = path.trim();
    if (path.length) {
        var folder = path.replace(/[^\/]*$/, '');
        (filesPerFolder[folder] = filesPerFolder[folder] || []).
            push(path.substr(folder.length));
    }
    return filesPerFolder;
}, {});
```

`filesPerFolder` will be

```
{
    "abc/xyz/../": [
        "a1.txt",
        "a2.txt",
        "a3.txt"
    ],
    "": [
        "no-folder.txt"
    ],
    "abc1/xyz/../": [
        "a4.txt",
        "a5.txt",
        "a6.txt"
    ]
}
```

The above code:

- recognises `LF` or `CRLF` line breaks
- skips white-space around paths
- skips empty lines
- can handle lines that have file names without folder prefix

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph6wvr9L/) where you can type the list as input, press the Go button and see the `Json` encoded `filesPerFolder`.

There are plenty of ways to work with that object. For instance, you could print out the contents as follows:

```
Object.keys(filesPerFolder).forEach(function(folder) {
    console.log('Contents of folder "' + folder + '": '
        + JSON.stringify(filesPerFolder[folder]));
});
```

This will output (with the example data above):

```
Contents of folder "abc/xyz/../": ["a1.txt","a2.txt","a3.txt"]
Contents of folder "": ["no-folder.txt"]
Contents of folder "abc1/xyz/../": ["a4.txt","a5.txt","a6.txt"]
```

Or, if you want to print each of the files with prefixed folder (which would be a clean version of the input):

```
Object.keys(filesPerFolder).forEach(function(folder) {
    filesPerFolder[folder].forEach(function(file) {
        console.log(folder + file);
    });
});
```

Output:

```
abc/xyz/../a1.txt
abc/xyz/../a2.txt
abc/xyz/../a3.txt
no-folder.txt
abc1/xyz/../a4.txt
abc1/xyz/../a5.txt
abc1/xyz/../a6.txt
```

Comment: i need separate list for same paths.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the list of paths is stored in one string:

```
var paths= "abc/xyz/../a1.txt"
           + "\n" + "abc/xyz/../a2.txt"
           + "\n" + "abc/xyz/../a3.txt"
           + "\n" + "abc1/xyz/../a4.txt"
           + "\n" + "abc1/xyz/../a5.txt"
           + "\n" + "abc1/xyz/../a6.txt";
```

You just need to split it by lines and reduce each entry to file name (e.g. by using regex):

```
var fileNamePattern = /[^\/]+$/;
var fileNames = paths.split("\n").map(function (entry) {
    return fileNamePattern.exec(entry)[0];
}
```

For more information about how to use regex look at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can find how to use the map method.

**Update**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2du3x1z/1/) you can find an example

Comment: can u make one fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming this is string*, first store different paths inside an array using `split` for newline in the string:

```
arr = str.split(/\n/);
```

Then loop over array and use `pop` to store file name in another array(say file_names):

```
file_names.push(arr[i].split('/').pop())
```